# Same SSH server key on a different SO

Tags: ssh, operating-system, ssh-keys

On a server running a SSH service, is it possible to keep its key when the server is updated to a different SO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just back them up and then copy them back when your new OS is installed.